# Strange lines over screen in Xfce

Tags: xfce, screen

I have installed Xfce on my PC. Everything works but a couple of transparent lines appear over all windows, as shown in the screenshot at below.

[image: these horizontal and vertical lines]

How I can remove the lines?

Comment: Where are those couple of transparent lines in this picture? Is that one vertical and one horizontal?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Grey bar appears when installed plank dock](https://askubuntu.com/questions/892886/grey-bar-appears-when-installed-plank-dock)

Answer (score 1):

from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/289481/line-across-the-entire-screen-that-occurs-only-when-running-xfce-with-a-dock-app

Uncheck Settings Manager > Window Manager Tweaks > Compositor > Show shadows under dock windows.

Answer (score 1):

Open Settings Manager by  -> Applications -> Settings ->> Settings Manager.

In Settings Manager window, open Window Manager Tweaks.

In Window Manager Tweaks, go to 'Compositor' tab.

Under the tab, disable shadow options.