# Grey bar appears when installed plank dock

Tags: display, themes, xfce, plank

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 and installed XFCE desktop environment right away. And then installed numix theme and icon pack. Then I installed plank. After installation a grey bar appears. When plank is closed it dissappears.

Here's an image:
[image: Plank placement: Bottom]

[image: Plank placement: Left]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I figured out the answer for my own question.

---

Steps:

- Open "Window Manager Tweaks" --> "Compositor" tab
- Uncheck "Show shadows under dock windows"


  (I'm using XFCE desktop environment.)