# How do I remove this horizontal line on my screen?

Tags: 18.04, screen

I'm using Xubuntu 18.04.

It shows up as long as I'm logged in, in any program as well as the desktop. But it's gone if I log out or lock the screen, i.e. it doesn't show up in lightdm.

**EDIT:** here are some better screenshots.

This is what it looks like after I just logged in.

[image: This is what it looks like after I just logged in.]

After a few seconds, the line shows up.

[image: After a few seconds, the line shows up.]

**EDIT 2:** Yes, I am indeed using Xfce and not GNOME. I just themed it with Papirus icons + Ant GTK theme, altered the look of the panel a bit, and then added a dock.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Grey bar appears when installed plank dock](https://askubuntu.com/questions/892886/grey-bar-appears-when-installed-plank-dock)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are indeed using Xubuntu 18.04, see [Horizontal Line Across Screen on Xfce](https://nochkawtf.wordpress.com/2015/05/03/horizontal-line-across-screen-on-xfce/)
 which has this advice:

> I finally found the fix: open Window Manager Tweaks and untick the ‘Show shadows under dock windows’ checkbox on the Compositor tab. It would remove shadows from under docks and deskbars.

Comment: Comparing with the screenshot in the post you linked to, it very much appears to be this issue indeed.

Comment: This also adds invisibility to Xfce transparent panels which otherwise show as a transparent shadow.